# Wait for user input using ActionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener

The user will input a guess, the program will check if it's larger or smaller than the randomly generated number and then loop again until the guess == number.

The gtf (guess text field) is where the user will input the guess and the ttf (times text field) is where the number of times the user have guessed is displayed.

The problem is that it just skips the if-statement (e.getSource() == gtf), it doesn't wait for the user to input a number into gtf. Can't you check twice for user action inside the actionPerformer? What other solutions could I use?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private int number, guess;
    private int time=0;
    private int result;
    private JButton btnStart;
    private JTextField ttf, gtf;
    private String msg;


//Constructor

public Test(){

    ttf = new JTextField();
    gtf = new JTextField();

    btnStart = new JButton("Start");
    btnStart.addActionListener(this);
    gtf.addActionListener(this);
    gtf.setEditable(false);    
    ttf.setEditable(false);
    msg = ("Guess a number: ");

    Container c = getContentPane();

    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
    c.add(new JLabel("Click to start the test: ", JLabel.RIGHT));
    c.add(btnStart);
    JLabel msglabel = new JLabel(msg, JLabel.RIGHT);
    msglabel.setForeground(Color.red);
    c.add(msglabel);
    c.add(gtf);
    c.add(new JLabel("Number of guesses: ", JLabel.RIGHT));
    c.add(ttf);

    setSize(600, 100);
    setTitle("Test");
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    if (e.getSource() == btnStart){

        gtf.setEditable(true);
        btnStart.setEnabled(false);

        Random generator = new Random();
        number = generator.nextInt(99) + 1;

        if (e.getSource() == gtf) {
        String g = gtf.getName();
        guess = Integer.parseInt(g);

        while(time<=9)
            {
                time++;
                ttf.setText(Integer.toString(time));

            if(guess>number)
                {
                   msg = (guess + "is too big. Try again: ");

                }   

           else if(guess<number)
                {
                   msg = (guess + " is too small. Try again: ");
                }   

           else if (guess==number)
           {
               break;
           }
       }


    result = (int) Math.ceil(time/3.0);

More code to print result...
```

Comment: BTW: `gtf.getName()` should be `gtf.getText()` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't you check twice for user action inside the actionPerformer?

No, Swing is event-based so only one component can trigger the `ActionEvent`. This means that you will need to place

```
if (e.getSource() == gtf) {
```

at an outer level of the `if` statement to check the source component (which will be triggered by pressing ENTER)

Comment: Thanks, but I have a follow up question. How could I wait for user input inside the while-loop?

Comment: You wouldnt. This would block the `EDT` and prevent UI updates. This sounds like an [`XY problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Each time the user guesses a number the msg label for gtf should be set (in each if-statement) and the user should be able to enter another number. This should repeat until time == 9 or guess == number (number is the randomly generated number). This wasn't the issue in the original post, I know...

Comment: That translates to replacing the while loop to an `if` statement block within the `gtf` if statement - probably better to give `gtf` its own `ActionListener` at this stage....

Comment: How would it look if you replace the while loop with an `if` statement? How will it loop then?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the `if (e.getSource() == gtf)` statement at all, becaus you start checking the input when the user clicks btnStart, so if you pass this statement `if (e.getSource() == btnStart)` then `if (e.getSource() == gtf)` will surely fail, so just remove it.

Comment: But then it will not wait for the user to input the guess?

Comment: Well, you have a start button right? so it will only go into the code when the user clicks start

Comment: Thats why you have `if (e.getSource() == btnStart)`

Comment: No, that's just to start the program. The textfield is disabled before that and shouldn't be enabled until the user starts the program.

Comment: I see, then you need to close the `if (e.getSource() == btnStart){` statement before this line `if (e.getSource() == gtf) {`